# PCB grounding through screw head

Tags: pcb, grounding, copper, corrosion

Can we use zinc plated screws for PCB grounding?
Means the zinc coated screw head will be in contact with copper trace on PCB for grounding.
But this can cause galvanic corrosion between zinc and copper.
Can you all advise me on this topic?
Can this cause galvanic corrosion?

Comment: Would the copper track not normally have something over it? Such as HASL or ENIG finish?  Also, what current (if any) do you expect to flow through the screw, and which way?

Comment: Why would the screw touch copper?  Wouldn't it touch the finished PCB surface?

Comment: Last time I did that, we were required to use star washer in between to guarantee it would bite though the playing and into the copper.

Comment: Jack B : Yes the copper layer will have an OSP layer

Comment: If super-concerned about it, assemble with dielectric grease.

Comment: Can you use brass screws instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't tolerate corrosion then don't use zinc on copper. If you look on the table below zinc on copper is ADE which means plating is consumed and corrosion increased. Another thing to consider is if the copper is plated then it will be zinc on nickel but I don't have info on that.

[image]
Source: http://www.preservationscience.com/materials/metals/PGC.html

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of printing solder paste over the OSP and reflow. I'm not recommending it, but I believe that's common with motherboards, for example. The main reason in that case would be for EMI mitigation, and perhaps nobody has checked motherboards for compliance after a few years.

Any connection that's not gas-tight has potential problems. If you really need a solid earth connection (for example, for *safety*) you may have to solder or stake a connector in.